# Embed a (public) tweet into Google Data Studio

Tags: twitter, embed, looker-studio

I am attempting to embed a public tweet into a Google Data Studio page. Side note - I wanted to use it like a tool tip so when a viewer would hover over a data point, the tweet would pop up, but I don't think that's possible.

My main issue is that, when attempting a URL Embed, I keep getting the error "Can't embed due to provider site restrictions." I tried using oEmbed API but that just produced the error "Can't load site."

I feel like there has to be a workaround (I can't use community connectors due to security issues, and can't use anything paid) that I just haven't come across yet.

Does anyone have any experience or knowledge of whether embedding a tweet into GDS is possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Data Studio's URL Embed creates an HTML iframe with the `src` set to the provided URL and thus has the same restrictions than iframe has.

Twitter has set the Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors directive to 'self' which prevents any other website from embedding their content.

For example, if you try it with https://wikipedia.org/ you'll see that the embed works because Wikipedia does not have this restriction.

> The frame-ancestors directive restricts the URLs which can embed the resource using frame, iframe, object, embed, or applet element.

Source: https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#directive-frame-ancestors